# Pictures wont save on Samsung Nexus

Tags: android

I have a Problem. I start from my own Application the Build-In Photoapplication with a Photo-Intent.

```
        String photoName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"; 

        File file = new File(getFilesDir(),//Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                //Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),
                photoName); // Anlegen der Datei im entsprechenden
                            // Verzeichnis
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(photoName, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intentPhoto.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
        //startActivity(intentPhoto);
        startActivityForResult(intentPhoto, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

This is my Code to start the Activity. As you can see, the first thing i do is to set up the file in the directory and then give the intent the location of the file to store it.

But everytime i take a picture it is not saved to the Pictures Directory. The only way to save the picture is to turn off the phone and restart it. Then every picture I have taken befor is there. This happens since the last updated to 4.1.1. Befor i updated the phone, everything worked fine, but since the update I have this problem.

Can somebody help me? Does anyone have the same Issue?

Comment: for clarification, when you say "Samsung Nexus" do you mean "Nexus S" or "Galaxy Nexus"? both are manufactured by Samsung.

Comment: Any any exceptions getting thrown when you try to close the files?  Ie.  are you seeing any stacktraces getting printed out?

Comment: @m0skit0 the Nexus tablet is by Asus not Samsung

Comment: It's a Galaxy nexus. The Problem is that every file is only written after reboot, but when i try to upload the file to a ftp-server(without reboot) for example there is no failure.In the File-System the photo only appears after Restart. The second Problem is when i try to get the URI Data with data.getData() from the intent ( in onActivityResult). Then i get a Failure because there isn't any data.

Comment: It works fine now, the problem was that i create the File by my self, with File file = new File(..);. But you have to use ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "IMG_"+ timeStamp+.jpg"); and put it into the intent to save the file at once without restarting the phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine now, the problem was that I create the File by my self, with:

```
File file = new File(..);
```

But you have to use:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "IMG_"+ timeStamp+.jpg");
```

And put it into the intent to save the file at once without restarting the phone.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you offer the new file to be scanned:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
          new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
          new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
      public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
          // code to execute when scanning is complete
      }
 });
```

You can pass in a null argument for the OnScanCompletedListener if you don't need to be notified when the scanner has picked it up, but you might want to at least put a logging statement there.